# Reasoning for awkward style of TreeMap.getHigherEntry

Tags: binary-search-trees

Consider a binary search tree (AVL, red-black, whatever). The goal "find the least key strictly greater than the specified one" ("upper_bound" in C++ STL, higherEntry//higherKey in Java, etc.) can be implemented in manner (Java-like pseudocode):

```
current = root;
bestsofar = null;
while (current != null) {
  if (example_key < current.key) {
    bestsofar = current;
    current = current.left;
  } else {
    current = current.right;
  }
}
// return for KV extracting
return bestsofar;
```

This can be improved with optimizations (e.g. [C5](https://github.com/sestoft/C5/blob/master/C5/Trees/TreeBag.cs#L3162) adds special processing case without comparings if found exact match), but the main principle remains that we use single pass from the root to a leaf.

But Java [TreeMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) implementation uses strange [variant](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk13/file/0368f3a073a9/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/TreeMap.java#l458) (the same at least in versions 8...13):

```
    Entry<K,V> p = root;
    while (p != null) {
        int cmp = compare(key, p.key);
        if (cmp < 0) {
            if (p.left != null)
                p = p.left;
            else
                return p;
        } else {
            if (p.right != null) {
                p = p.right;
            } else {
                Entry<K,V> parent = p.parent;
                Entry<K,V> ch = p;
                while (parent != null && ch == parent.right) {
                    ch = parent;
                    parent = parent.parent;
                }
                return parent;
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
```

so, in some cases it backtracks using "parent" link to find the place it started passing only left-side links before final right-side dead end. (Really, all 4 key-based inexact searches utilizes this way, with minor differences and mirrored conditions.)

What case is being optimized with this approach?

Comment: Nice observation! Could you also mention getLowerEntry, getFloorEntry and getCeilingEntry of Java in the question, since they all use that "strange" approach?

Comment: An obvious answer is that this strange approach in Java optimizes the case when bestsofar is not used. The crux of the question is, then, how often does that happen? Which approach is faster in general, in average or in particular cases? Anyway, the approach that keeps track of the best so far is much simpler to code and clearer to understand.

Comment: @greybeard "null", of course. Thanks, fixed.